# When are these additional docked cell styles used?

Tags: stylesheet, undocumented, docked-cell

The style `"DockedCell"` is automatically used for Docked Cells even when no [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell.html) style is specified.  In the section of `Core.nb` where `"DockedCell"` is defined there are also these styles:

- "SystemDockedCell"
- "DockedTitleCell"
- "PluginDockedCell"

**When or where are these styles used?**

The names suggest to me that they are intended for automatic rather than manual application.  I can find no mention of them in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used in the file `MiscExpressions.tr` to define various toolbars, "PluginToolbar", "StylesheetToolbar" etc.

In version 9, you can find them using

```
nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
       "FrontEnd", "TextResources"}, "MiscExpressions.tr"]]; 
NotebookFind[nb, "PluginDockedCell"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In version 10.4.1 for Windows *MiscExpressions.tr* contains definitions for

- 20 `"SystemDockedCell"`s:

  - `"SlideshowToolbar"`
  - `"PackageToolbar"`
  - `"SecurityToolbar"`
  - `"DynamicUpdatingToolbar"`
  - `"CodeCaptionToolbar"`
  - `"WolframCloudSyncToolbar"`
  - `"PluginUpdateStripe"`
  - `"BuiltInStylesheetToolbar"`
  - `"StylesheetToolbar"`
  - `"VersionedStylesheetToolbar"`
  - `"TrialBar"`
  - `"StudentBar"`
  - `"HomeEditionBar"`
  - `"OriginalEducationalStripe"`
  - `"OriginalFreeStripe"`
  - `"OriginalDemonstrationUseStripe"`
  - `"OriginalStripeFooter"`
  - `"PluginEducationalStripe"`
  - `"PluginFreeStripe"`
  - `"PluginDemonstrationUseStripe"`
- 2 `"DockedTitleCell"`s

  - `"BuiltInStylesheetToolbar"`
  - `"StylesheetToolbar"`
- 1 `"PluginDockedCell"`:

  - `"PluginToolbar"`
- 2 toolbars with `"CompatibilityDocked1"` & `"CompatibilityDocked2"`:

  - `"CompatibilityToolbar"`
  - `"CompatibilityToolbarPostScan"`
- 1 toolbar with `"DockedCell"` & `"DockedLinkTrail"`:

  - `"HelpViewerToolbar"`

The ones that are listed more than once either contain multiple `Cell`s with different style specifications or a single `Cell` with multiple style specifications.

On can examine these toolbars by evaluating for example

```
FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "SecurityToolbar"] // CellPrint
```